# Produce Insert SQL queries from a Dictionary using LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012

Apologies if the question is misleading, but I will try my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a dictionary with the following values

```
Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
myDictionary.Add(1, 100)
myDictionary.Add(2, 200)
myDictionary.Add(3, 300)
myDictionary.Add(4, 400)
myDictionary.Add(5, 500)
myDictionary.Add(6, 600)
```

I am producing some insert queries by looping through the Dictioanry as below:

```
Dim s As String = String.Empty
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)
    s &= "INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT " & kvp.key & "," & kvp.value & ";" & vbCrLf
Next

Console.Write(s)
```

The values that get saved into my String variable are as below:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 1, 100;
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 2, 200;
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 3, 300;
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 4, 400;
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 5, 500;
INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT 6, 600;
```

Then, I will insert these values into the database as below:

```
myDb.ExecuteSQL(s)
```

I am happy with the above, but would like to explore/learn new ways. As such, I would like to know if is there a way to produce the aforementioned output with the `LINQ` expressions?
For Example: an expression that saves the `INSERT` queries into a `List(of String)`

```
Dim myList As New String(of String)
myList = <LINQ expression here>
```

So, I can use the following to print it on the console and insert in my database.

```
console.Write(String.Join(vbCrLf, myList.ToString()))
myDb.ExecuteSQL(String.Join(vbCrLf, myList.ToString()))
```

**EDIT:**
I am aware of the `parameterized SQL` usage, `SQL Injection` etc and I have been using them in my project. The above example is just to keep things simple and explain what I'm trying to achieve. 
I'm interested to know if there is a way to achieve the same with the `LINQ` (it wouldn't necessarily need to be cleaner), thank you.

Comment: I would say the *first* thing to learn about is using parameterized SQL instead of including values directly in your SQL.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet. You can use `DataAdapter`and `DataSet` using `InsertCommand` for ADO.NET. This will be more structural, parameterized and error-safe.

Comment: @SamMakin Oops, fixed :)

Comment: @user3021830 Unless you are maintaining legacy code avoid `DataSet` and `DataAdapter`, then just add lots of data movement and dependency on more designers without any real benefit. If you want that kind of functionality use an ORM. However in both cases you should know how to use connections, commands and data readers because when you debug issues with higher level tools you'll need to know what they are doing.

Comment: `Dim commands = myDictionary.Select(Function(x) new string("INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) SELECT " & x.Key & "," & x.Value & ";"))` but really this is not better than your current code an  less readable.

Comment: @Richard, I totally agree on the use of ORM. But just thought to start with some basics of the concept of Data Access. But the use of ORM would be my personal choice as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Richard, Steve, user3021830: I agree with all your comments and I've been using the parameterized SQL in my project. The above example is just to keep things simple and to explain what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you all for your comments, very informative indeed.

Answer (score 2):

> f is there a way to produce the aforementioned output with the LINQ expressions?

Yes, but it is not necessarily any cleaner.

Something like, in C# (because VB lambdas look horrible)

```
// Get IEnum<string>, one SQL command per string
// NB. enumerating a dictionary gives IEnum<KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>>
var exprs = myDictionary.Select(kv =>
                // Build SQL
            );

var cmdStr = String.Join("\r\n", exprs);
```

*However* this is **BAD**. You should be using parameters to pass values to the database to help avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

This is easier with the loop:

```
var params = new List<DbParameter>();
int nParam = 0;
var sb = new StringBuider();

foreach (var kv in myDictionary) {
  sb.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO myTable(id, qty) values (@p{0}, @p{1})",
                  nParam, nParam+1);
  sb.AppendLine();
  params.Add(MakeDbParam("@p" + nParam.ToString(), kv.Key);
  params.Add(MakeDbParam("@p" + (nParam+1).ToString(), kv.Value);
  nParam +=2
}
```

And then include the parameter collection when executing the command.

Comment: I agree with your comments and I've been using the parameterized SQL in my project. The above example is just to keep things simple and explain what I'm trying to achieve. I'm interested to know if there is a way to achieve the same with the `LINQ` (it wouldn't necessarily need to be cleaner). Thank you for your comments, very informative.